# Equal Column width on a table created by divs

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a page with 2 equal columns. I am using divs to create tables. I want each column to take up 50% of the table width. I have tried this (and other combinations) and have had no success.

```
.tableview
{
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}
.tablerow
{
    display:table-row;
}
.tablecell
{
    display:table-cell;
    width=100%;
}
```

and for my html...

```
<div class="tableview">
    <div class="tablerow">
        <div class="tablecell">
            ABOUT ALYSSA
            buch of text buch of text buch of text buch of text buch of textbuch of text buch of text buch of text buch of textbuch of text
        </div>
        <div class="tablecell">
            <img src="images/alyssa.jpg" width=100%/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should correct typo mistake (`width: 100%;` instead of `width=100%;`) and set each column width to 50%.

```css
.tableview {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.tablerow {
  display: table-row;
}
.tablecell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableview">
  <div class="tablerow">
    <div class="tablecell">
      ABOUT ALYSSA buch of text buch of text buch of text buch of text buch of textbuch of text buch of text buch of text buch of textbuch of text
    </div>
    <div class="tablecell">
      <img src="images/alyssa.jpg" width=100%/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I will accept the answer in 9 minutes!

Comment: I am having some issues now if I have two sets of text in each column that don't take up at least that amount. For example if one column simply had the text "hello" and the other column "world" it renders "Hello World" right next to each other instead of half way across the page... do you know anythign about that?

Answer (score 0):

change to `width: 50%` you had `width=100%`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/25vp1bav/)